# CSS positioning anomaly Safari/Chrome

Tags: css, webkit

Please see the following example:

http://6329195.com/stackoverflow/css_li_weird/index.html

If you refresh the page, every once in awhile one of the images will move down to be noticeably out of line with the others. It doesn't appear to happen in Firefox. It only happens every once in awhile. Most often it happens to the last image, but it can occur to any/multiple at a time. You can view a screenshot of the problem here:

[image]

http://6329195.com/stackoverflow/css_li_weird/screenshot.jpg

Can anyone tell me what is wrong/why it does this?

(The list is ultimately used for a jQuery slideshow, hence the blank href in the a tags)

Comment: It's due to the `display: block` on the `a` tags.

Comment: I'm assuming you've changed something, because I can't get it to do it anymore.

Comment: I just tried this. After a dozen refreshes, the third one jumped down: http://6329195.com/stackoverflow/css_li_weird/index2.html

Comment: I didn't change the original file, sometimes it takes quite a number of refreshes to get the problem to appear. Other times, it happens frequently

Comment: I got it to display, but upon inspecting the element, it went back up to the proper place! I'm stumped as to why it displays like that.

Comment: I tried many times but sooner or later it displays the same problem. I made a jsfiddle for everyone: [http://jsfiddle.net/rtppE/](http://jsfiddle.net/rtppE/)

Comment: @jmeas that is very weird. On my regular website (with many other elements) it stays in the lower position and there is no indication as to why the element is doing that

Comment: Everyone...there seems to be a glitch with the overflow:hidden on the list item. I removed that (don't really need it) and now it seems to work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

[A similar question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007904/1085891) lead me to try `vertical-align: top;` which appears to work. So, if for some reason you did need to keep `overflow:hidden;` then this might be a way to prevent the glitch/bug.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rtppE/2/

```
li.productMenuItem{
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 45px;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden
}
```